# Unable to load Lotus Domino V11 version library due to libcrypto64.so.1.1 on AIX

Tags: openssl, lotus-domino, libcrypto

I am getting below error while loading libnotes_r.a on AIX. I am using Domino lotus V11. Libcrypto does not contain libcrypto64.so.1.1.
0509-022 Cannot load module /opt/hcl/domino/notes/latest/ibmpow/libnotes_r.a.
0509-150   Dependent module /usr/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto64.so.1.1) could not be loaded.
0509-152   Member libcrypto64.so.1.1 is not found in archive

```
ar -xv libcrypto.a
x - libcrypto.so
x - libcrypto.so.1.0.0
x - libcrypto.so.0.9.8
x - libcrypto.so.1.0.2
```

How Can I provide libcrypto64.so.1.1 which does not present in libcrypto.a?

Comment: On AIX, compiling OpenSSL (or anything) from source is not easy. If your system is modern enough, you can try this: 'yum search openssl`

Comment: Please make sure that you are on a supported platform (AIX 7.2 TL1+ as per https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0077033 ) and open a ticket with HCL. This should work without having to compile libcrypto64.so.